# LSP Typescript for Sublime Text does not recognize element.style

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, sublimetext, language-server-protocol

I am using Sublime Text 4 with LSP-Typescript for Javascript autocompletion. In general it works, but it does not recognize `element.style` and it does not provide any autocompletion for this. Any ideas how to settle this?

An example:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id='mainDIV'></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
#mainDIV {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
}
```

**script.js**

```
const mainDIV = document.querySelector("#mainDIV");
mainDIV.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @MattDMo I added an example